# Вывод структуры переменных C/C++

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! Пытался найти в C/C++ аналог print_r var_dump из php для вывода структуры переменных, но безрезультатно.
И Случайно увидел в журнале такой скриншот, где как раз то, что мне нужно.
[image: скриншот]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за программа? :)

Comment: Научитесь пользоваться отладчиком. Не пожалеете.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен дебаг (отладка) средствами IDE или отдельным запуском из-под дебаггера с отладочной информацией при сборке, смотря чем пользуетесь при написании кода и под что вообще пишете. В php аналогичный инструмент - xDebug.

Answer (score 1):

Да любая IDE/любой редактор со встроенным отладчиком (кучи их). Или надстройка над системным отладчиком (их тоже немало, особенно в Linux). Для примера:

1) Отладка в Eclipse/CDT:

[image: Eclipse/CDT]

2) Nemiver - одна из многочисленных графических надстроек над gdb (линуксовый отладчик):

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 1):

Любой нормальный отладчик это умеет, втом числе и Visual studio